# On-premise software to implement my own idP Identity Provider

Tags: authentication, user-management, openid

I want implement an identity provider. I am researching about it, but I found any software that was only **"identity layer"** without any solution for **"user store"** like shibboleth. I have below require:
1- I want to give authentication/authorization to any other web site and app.
2- I will have multiple application which will need single point sign on.
Note: I need a software that have **user store** for store username, password and other attribute of users in my local, around of authN/authZ solution or integrated with any identity layer like shibboleth.
Note: I don't want using any online services like Azure or product of any other company. I need a on-premises solution.
Note: I don't want using the other idP like google, yahoo and etc.
Note: Not important language of program and OS, because it should be SOA. but C# and windows are better. Open source and free is good.

Comment: OP joined, was active for week, and has been absent for over a year since. I doubt that he is coming back

Answer (score 0):

I have tried Keylock and miniOrange On-Premise IDP, both worked very well for me and as you stated your requirement above, this can also work for you. they have UI  which is very helpful, unlike Shibboleth. They both have all essential IAM features.

Find this may be it can help you- https://idp.miniorange.com/#home
                                  http://www.keycloak.org/

Answer (score 0):

I would propose [keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) as an all-in-one solution